# How to use get to set model attributes from a nested object

Tags: backbone.js, collections, nested, models, marionette

Can anyone help with this problem? I have nested data which I am trying to set in the initialize event of my Marionette/Backbone model. Here is an example:

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "name": "Coke",
            "description": "Fizzy drink",
            "price": [
                {
                    "retail": 2.50,
                    "shop": 3.50
                }
             ],
        },
       ...
```

So, I can get at this data in the model's initialize funciton like this:

```
...
initialize: function() {
    this.name = this.get('name');
    this.description = this.get('description');
}
```

To get the price, I have tried, for instance:

```
this.price = this.get('price[0].shop');
```

... and many other variations.

My question is, how do I get the price out of this structure?

The price will end up in a standard template e.g. <%= price %>

many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are getting `name` like this `this.get('name')` as you said, then to get `shop`, try below.

```
this.price = this.get('price')[0].shop;
```

Comment: I'm marking this as correct because it is correct! However, I have another problem allied to this which I'll do a separate question. Many thanks!